# nginx redirect from localhost to http://_/

Tags: nginx, wget

I'm having a strange issue: when I'm asking this url from inside my nginx server, in server command line (connection via ssh) or from outside the server, with curl or wget:

```
ubuntu@test.myserver.com: $ wget https://test.myserver.com/print/document/view/1729 --no-check-certificate
```

I'm getting this response:

```
--2016-02-22 01:28:49--  https://test.myserver.com/print/document/view/1729
Resolviendo test.myserver.com (test.myserver.com)... 1.2.3.4
Conectando con test.myserver.com (test.myserver.com)[1.2.3.4]:443... conectado.
AVISO: no se puede verificar el certificado de test.myserver.com, emitido por “emailAddress=info@test.myserver.com,CN=test.myserver.com,OU=Test,O=Test,L=Test,ST=Test,C=ES”:
  Se encontró un certificado autofirmado.
    AVISO: el nombre común “myserver.com” del certificado no encaja con el nombre de equipo “test.myserver.com” solicitado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 302 Moved Temporarily
Ubicación: http://_/print/document/view/1729 [siguiente]
--2016-02-22 01:28:49--  http://_/print/document/view/1729
Resolviendo _ (_)... falló: Nombre o servicio desconocido.
wget: no se pudo resolver la dirección del equipo “_”
```

But when requested from Firefox in my computer (outside server) `https://test.myserver.com/print/document/view/1729` works fine and getting response code 200 (no 302 redirect anywhere). When requested with Chrome the error is the same. Here it is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    server_name _;
    root /var/www/drupal;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.key;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
    }

    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        # try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal <= 6
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    # Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in the middle,
    # such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict, and only allows this pattern
    # with the update.php front controller.  This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
    # blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If you do not have
    # any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a laxer rule, such as:
    #   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    # The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL pattern with front
    # controllers other than update.php in a future release.
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal <= 6
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal >= 7
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location ~* ^((?!system).)*\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

I need to be able to access to public ip from server itself because it's being used by phantomjs to generate pdf from url.

Any suggestion on how to configure nginx?

Comment: Is the resolved IP address correct? Check your resolvers, /etc/hosts.

Comment: What do you mean? In fact `host test.myserver.com` resolves to public ip

Comment: I've seen that this is happening also with curl or wget from external machine, not with browser...

Answer (score 0):

At the end was a question of website redirection and `$_SERVER` variables:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == '_';                 // as configured in nginx.conf
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']   == 'test.myserver.com'; // extracted from request
```